# (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position using openlayers js)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson

I am trying to insert a map with WFS request from GeoServer with OpenLayers tool but I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Jl (ol.js:342)
    at wm.k.Pa (ol.js:342)
    at T.<anonymous> (ol.js:340)
```

and this is my code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
</center> 
<script>
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/opengeo/ows?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=opengeo:comgeo&' +
          'maxFeatures=50'+
          'outputFormat=application%2Fjson' ;

        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      })
        ],
        target: document.getElementById('mapid'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-9, 30],
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 5
        })
      });
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I don't know where is the problem because I didn't found anything with JSON problems and OpenLayers.

Comment: check what is in the "json" file because it is probably an XML response indicating a GeoServer error.